# Xcode Image Asset Catelogue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, xcasset

I would like to use backgroundimage on `UIButton` with little arrow at bottom.

In `Assest catalogue`  I have slice image but result is not what I want.

[image]

Result

[image]

is there anyway I can add another vertical line? I could use exact size but button size is changing at different place.

Comment: Does anyone have solution?

Comment: you can create a dynamic path using `UIBezierCurves` for the contour, and that would solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end I used excellent third party tool.

[PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/)

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/